# When to use ext format of msgpack?

Tags: msgpack

I just began to study msgpack this summer. The reason to study msgpack is plan to use that for internal message protocol for a scientific data sampling software.

Well, when I read the spec of msgpack, and it's confused for me about the ext format. My confusion is when to use ext format in message exchange. Why does msgpack provide such kind of thing? Any requirement or example on that?

Comment: I think the [msgpack specification](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#types-extension-type) explains this. Apparently for Application specific types.

Comment: yes. but i couldn't find an example on that. i can't see what application would be requiring this ext format. i want to know more on this.